# Can animals also praise God like us Christians

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

We were debating on Psalm 150:6 help me what does the Bible means when it says "let everything that has BREATH praise the LORD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so fast - we need to keep in mind that the Bible, especially Hebrew, is extremely rich in metaphors.  For example:

- Job 12:8 - Or speak to the earth, and it will teach you; let the fish of the sea inform you.
- Job 38:7 - while the morning stars sang together and all the sons of God shouted for joy?
- Isa 55:12 - You will indeed go out with joy and be led forth in peace; the mountains and hills will burst into song before you, and all the trees of the field will clap their hands.
- Ps 19:1-4 - The heavens declare the glory of God; the skies proclaim the work of His hands. Day after day they pour forth speech; night after night they reveal knowledge. Without speech or language, without a sound to be heard, their voice has gone out into all the earth, their words to the ends of the world.
- Ps 150:6 - Let everything that has breath praise the LORD!

Presumably, what the psalmist and other Bible writers are saying is: is saying amounts to the idea expressed by Paul in Rom 1:20 -

> For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal power and divine
> nature, have been clearly perceived, ever since the creation of the
> world, in the things that have been made. So they are without excuse.

That is, for those who care to notice, God's "fingerprints" are all over His creation and all these things show how great He is!!